# iOS 14 DispatchQueue.main.async not working

Tags: xcode, ios14

I have this code that was working perfectly and when I updated to ios 14 it stopped working.

Debugging the app I noticed that the code inside the closure was not working.

```
func replaceWindowRootWith(flow: Flow, step: Step, fadeAnimation: Bool = true, addDelay: Bool = false) -> FlowContributors {
    Flows.whenReady(flow1: flow) { [weak self] root in
        root.hero.isEnabled = true
        root.hero.modalAnimationType = fadeAnimation ? .fade : .none
        if let currentRoot = self?.window?.rootViewController {
            let delay = addDelay ? 0.2 : 0
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
                print("REPLACING - \(step.self)")
                Hero.shared.cancel(animate: false)
                currentRoot.hero.replaceViewController(with: root)
            }
        } else {
            self?.window?.rootViewController = root
            self?.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
    return .one(flowContributor: .contribute(withNextPresentable: flow,
                                             withNextStepper: OneStepper(withSingleStep: step)))
}
```

The code inside the DispatchQueue closure doesn't run. Anyone had the same problem or found a solution to this yet?

Comment: You didn't have any problems with dispatchQueue in ios14?

That is just illustrative none of the code I have inside the closure works

Comment: I've updated my question to make it clearer...

Comment: I posted the actual code. breakpoint hits this line: let delay = addDelay ? 0.2 : 0 then doesn't hit breakpoint inside the closure

Comment: Yes it is ready. When something is working normally and just a ios update messes it up. People could have found similar problems and/or a solution. Just by a dispatchqueue being fired and not activated is something strange and NOT DEBUGABLE. hence the questions to check if more people have similar issues.

Comment: But that is an explanation when you have hundreds of users that update to ios14 and with the same production build the app stops working. I would call that magically bugged the app

Comment: Many people are reporting this error, in my project it happens too

Comment: I think this could be Hero related issue. I've changed to OperationQueue.main.addOperation and the print is shown but the transition is not executed. But still very strange why wouldn't dispatchqueue.main print out the output since absolutely no lines of code where changed since a build run in ios13 which was working now ios14 stops printing... that is strange just by itself.

Comment: Wish I could share the screenshot but I have a similar situation where IS_dispatch_source is showing a circular reference loop in the memory allocations showing the app is stuck in a terce NSRunLoop outside the normal one while whipping around code blocks.
There are a bunch of leaks reported in libsystem_blocks.dylib which are related to this loop.

Our application do not exhibit these problems under iOS13. Just downloaded XC12.1 and the iOS14.1 sim in there still shows the problem. So no changes/help from that.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I get when turning one every memory analysis I can when launching our app. With a bit of luck, I can always find this runloop stuck from a code block.

I have a number of code-blocks chained up to get to that display. I removed some animation-related blocks to simplify runtime yet no cigare. Still looking into it but there is definitly something REALLY fishy in iOS 14 code blocks.

This is also reproducible under iOS SIM 14.1 from XC12.1-GM.

[image: NSRunloop stuck in dispatch]